# Problem while nodejs connecting with MYSQL which is connected by mongodb with JWT authentication

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, jwt

Problem while nodejs connecting with MYSQL which is connected by mongodb with JWT authentication
            AM using nodejs mongodb jwt redux based authentication.Now am converting it to mysql db which is showing email or password incorrect.I have commented monodb code.I have mentioned ******** for mongdb configuration.I want to know why it is showing email or password incorrect for mysql itself.

```
        loginAdmin.js
     // Imports
        import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

        // App Imports
        import params from '../../../setup/config/params'
        import validate from '../../../setup/helpers/validation'
        import { logCreate } from '../../log/mutation'
        //import User, { collection as user } from '../model'  //Mongodb********
        import authResponse from './authResponse'

        import Sequelize from 'sequelize'

        const sequelize = new Sequelize('dusminute', 'root', '', {
          host: 'localhost',
          //dialect: /* one of 'mysql' | 'mariadb' | 'postgres' | 'mssql' */
          dialect: 'mysql' 
        });
        sequelize
          .authenticate()
          .then(() => {
            console.log('SETUP - Database Connected....');
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
          });

        const User = sequelize.define('user', {
          // attributes
            email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
          }

        }, {
          // options
        });

        // Login
        export default async function loginAdmin({ params: { email, password }, translate }) {
         var qry1,data1;
          // Validation rules
          const rules = [
            {
              data: { value: email },
              check: 'email',
              message: translate.t('user.messages.fields.email')
            },
            {
              data: { value: password, length: params.user.rules.passwordMinLength },
              check: 'lengthMin',
              message: translate.t('user.messages.fields.passwordMinLength', { length: params.user.rules.passwordMinLength })
            }
          ]

          // Validate
          try {
            validate(rules)
          } catch(error) {
            throw new Error(error.message)
          }

          // Check if user exists with same email
          try {
            // Get user
            //MongoDB *****************************
            // const user = await User.findOne({ email })
            // console.log(user)
            // if(user) {
            //  const passwordsMatch =  bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
            //   if (passwordsMatch) {
            //     return {
            //       data: authResponse(user),
            //       message: translate.t('user.login.messages.success')
            //     }
            //   }
            // }


            User
          .findOrCreate({where: {email: email,role:'admin'},attributes: ['role','isVerified','isPublished','isDeleted','id','email','password','name','mobile','image','createdAt','updatedAt']})
          .then(([users, created]) => {
            const user=users.get({plain: true})
            console.log(user);
            if(user) {
             const passwordsMatch =  bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
              if (passwordsMatch) {
                data1= authResponse(user)
                console.log(data1)
                return {
                  data: authResponse(user),
                  message: translate.t('user.login.messages.success')
                }
              }
            }
            /*
             findOrCreate returns an array containing the object that was found or created and a boolean that
             will be true if a new object was created and false if not, like so:

            [ {
                username: 'sdepold',
                job: 'Technical Lead JavaScript',
                id: 1,
                createdAt: Fri Mar 22 2013 21: 28: 34 GMT + 0100(CET),
                updatedAt: Fri Mar 22 2013 21: 28: 34 GMT + 0100(CET)
              },
              true ]

         In the example above, the array spread on line 3 divides the array into its 2 parts and passes them
          as arguments to the callback function defined beginning at line 39, which treats them as "user" and
          "created" in this case. (So "user" will be the object from index 0 of the returned array and
          "created" will equal "true".)
            */
          })



            } catch (error) {
            //await logCreate({ params: { payload: { method: 'userLogin', message: error.message } } })

            throw new Error(translate.t('common.messages.error.server'))
          }

          throw new Error(translate.t('user.login.messages.error.wrongCredentials'))
        }


        authResponse.js
        // Imports
        import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

        // App Imports
        import { SECURITY_SECRET } from '../../../setup/config/env'

        // Auth Response (token and user info)
        export default function userAuthResponse(user) {

          //user = user.toJSON() //mongodb***********************
         //user=user[0];
          delete user.password
        //console.log(user.id)
          return {
            token: jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, SECURITY_SECRET),//mongodb********
            //token: jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, SECURITY_SECRET),//mysql
            user: user
          }
        }

        query.js
        export function login({ email, password }, isLoading = true) {

          return async dispatch => {
            dispatch({
              type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
              isLoading
            })

            dispatch({
              type: MESSAGE_SHOW,
              message: 'Please wait..'
            })

            try {
              const { data } = await axios.post(API_URL,  {
                operation: 'userLoginAdmin',
                params: { email, password }
              })

              let message = ''

              if(data.success) {alert('success')
                console.log(data.data.user)
                dispatch(setUser(data.data.token, data.data.user))

                setUserLocally(data.data.token, data.data.user)

                message = `Login successful. Welcome back, ${ data.data.user.name }.`
              } else {console.log(data)
                message = data.message
              }

              dispatch({
                type: MESSAGE_SHOW,
                message
              })
            } catch(error) {
              dispatch({
                type: MESSAGE_SHOW,
                message: 'Please try again.'
              })
            } finally {
              dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_RESPONSE
              })
            }
          }
        }`enter code here`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBiMK.png)
Plz see the output screen below image

Comment: Email or password are incorrect. Check them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a success message when hooking up to the database initially..  Does this line print?

```
console.log('SETUP - Database Connected....');
```